# mvc2 dropdownlist dynamic parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
 <%   string disabled="new {disabled='disabled'}"; %>

  <%= Html.DropDownList("clientId", someObject, disabled)%>
```

In the above code I want the text disabled to be replaced by what ever value I set that string to. When I check the HTML source on the page, I see that new `{disabled='disabled'}` has been added as a new item in the dropdown list instead of a property.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of `DropDownList` helper must be an object that contains the HTML attributes or object of type `IDictionary<string, object>`.
This is the proper solution:

```
<% var disabled = new { disabled = "disabled" }; %>
```